# JQuery Datepicker UI transparent

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have this problem which the JQuery Datepicker went transparent. Dates are still able to send data into the database and things that are required to add have added in already.

**Files that I have imported:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**The datepicker just appear in this way**

[image: The picker just appear this way]

**My html codes is over here**

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="dateFrom" class="col-md-2 control-label">Date From:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group date">
                                    <input type="text" id="dateFrom" name="dateFrom" class="form-control col-sm-2" required value="<?php echo $defaultFromDate ?>"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            <label for="dateTo" class="col-md-2 control-label">Date To:</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="input-group date">
                                    <input type="text"  id="dateTo" name="dateTo" class="form-control col-sm-2" required value="<?php echo $defaultToDate ?>"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

**Script is here**

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#dateFrom, #dateTo").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
            if (this.id == 'dateFrom') {
                var dateMin = $('#dateFrom').datepicker("getDate");
                var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 0);
                var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(), dateMin.getDate() + 120);
                $('#dateTo').datepicker("option", "minDate", rMin);
                $('#dateTo').datepicker("option", "maxDate", rMax);
            }
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you show your Javascript? Even better, give a working sample?

Comment: @macl added my script above

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Your code is missing a JqueryUI theme. Try to add, for example:

```
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Working sample [here](https://jsbin.com/quyajesowa/edit?html,output)

Comment: Thanks mate,you've been a great help! Nice and UI appeared.